# Share Database using between 2 computers in the same room using network connection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, networking

i have developed a desktop application and the data base supposed to be used by the doctor and the nurse in the same room but from 2 different computers , i want to share the data base between them without any net connections to give the doctor the ability to see any changes the nurse do in the data base using the Application
the database is made using MSSQL server 2005 and Visual Studio 2008 C#
this is the first time and i donknow how to make it works

Comment: Is there any other solution to make the two computer access the same Database , just any other way

Comment: You want them to share a resource without having a way to share it. What do you think?

Comment: sorry you are right there should be a way to share it , my fault , but i donknow how ?

Comment: [link](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-13419-how-to-create-a-lan)

Comment: i think i can make a LAN using help from this site ,

Answer (score 3):

A database is supposed to be a shared resource. A network connection to the database from both computers will be required.

When you connect to the database server, the [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) you provide include a server name. This must be the network name of the server.

Comment: where the data base suppose to be and what should i do , i really don get it ,

Comment: Preferably on a dedicated server, but alternatively on one of the workstations. However, if you go for that option, this computer must be turned on and connected to the network - otherwise the other computer can't access the database.

Comment: Okay , the database on the computer of the doctor and it always turned on , how other PC will be connected to it and see the data base that attached to the SQL server ?

Comment: i will make a LAN connection , should i modify or add any code to the Project ?